# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tostring'

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ffmpeg

So I just started programming a few days ago and I have this problem: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tostring'`. I don't know what is wrong.

```
#Reads through each frame, calculates the timestamp, places it on the frame and
#exports the frame to the output video.
while current_frame < total_frames:
    success, image = video.read()
    elapsed_time = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
    current_frame = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    timestamp = initial + dt.timedelta(microseconds = elapsed_time*1000)
    cv2.putText(image, 'Date: ' + str(timestamp)[0:10], (50,int(height-150)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)
    cv2.putText(image, 'Time: ' + str(timestamp)[11:-4], (50,int(height-100)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)
    pipe.stdin.write(image.tostring())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some frames aren't returning correctly, and so the `image` variable is empty and hence is `NoneType`, that is, it has no type.

Check the shape of the image using `image.shape`.

You can also check the type of any variable in Python with `type(variable)`.

`if image.shape[0]==0 or image.shape[1]==0: 
   continue #or do something else to handle this`

Comment: this looks like a comment, not an answer to the question.